# How to data entry for a matched case control study

Tags: matching

Please tell me how to enter my samples in excel can I first enter cases then controls in same sheet? 
What about match ID and group indicator?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real wrong way to enter data, as **you can always manipulate your data and rearrange it** in statistical software like R. That said, to avoid errors from confusion and headaches from remembering what's what, here is what I suggest:

A convenient way is by starting with a row that represents the column names. **Every next row then represents a single observation** of all recorded variables. For example, using the variables you mentioned:

```
matchID | group | status  | ... 
1       | A     | case    | ...
2       | A     | control | ...
3       | A     | case    | ...
...     | ...   | ...     | ...
1000    | B     | control | ...
```

The order in which you enter the observations is not so important.

If you have **repeated measures** of the same individuals or experimental units, you can still use this format by simply creating new rows where `matchID` repeats:

```
matchID | group | status  | time | ... 
1       | A     | case    | 1    | ...
2       | A     | control | 1    | ...
3       | A     | case    | 1    | ...
...     | ...   | ...     | ...  | ...
1000    | B     | control | 1    | ...
1       | A     | case    | 2    | ...
2       | A     | control | 2    | ...
3       | A     | case    | 2    | ...
...     | ...   | ...     | ...  | ...
1000    | B     | control | 2    | ...
```

**Make sure to use informative variable names**, so that both you and others can understand what represents what, even if some time passes between data collection and analysis. Try to avoid using special characters (`!@#$%^&*()[]{}/\:;'",.<>`) and spaces, because these may have meaning in the statistical software you end up using.

**Abbreviations** like `temp` for temperature, and `conc` for concentration are fine, but make sure the abbreviations are still recognizable without a glossary.

If you must use more than a single word or abbreviation to describe your variable in an unambiguous way, there are two naming conventions that I would consider good:

- Capitalize each word (or each word after the first), like `MatchID` or `matchID`;
- Underscores as spaces, like `match_ID`.

Of course, try to keep your column names short. If every patient has but a single identifier, you can drop `match` altogether and just name the first variable `ID`, or `patient`.

---

Finally, since you mention using Excel specifically, avoid the following:

- Graphs in the middle of a page with raw data;
- Coloring;
- Multiple data sets arranged side-by-side.

Whether it be yourself or someone else, the moment you want to use your data in a different program than Excel, **these features most likely will not transfer well**. If you like using these features, you can instead:

- Create a graph on a different tab;
- Work with coloring in a copy of your raw data (in another tab or file);
- Create separate files or at least tabs for separate data frames.